# How to update a MySQL table column without erasing the existing data

Tags: mysql

I have a table `ticket` with a column `comments`. I want a MySQL query where I can add values into comments without erasing the previously stored data. Also the new data should be added in a new line.

For Example if the present content of coloumns table is abc and the new data is def it should update the database as def(in 1st line) and abc (in second line)

I have used the below query. It works but here it is hitting the database as `abc;def`

```
UPDATE ticket 
SET comments = concat( coalesce( comments ) , 'def' ) 
WHERE ticket_id =235;
```

Here `ticket_id` is a primary key.

Comment: I tried your code and I don't get the `;` between the old text and newly added text. Is that your code copied exactly as you run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to put a new line or a carriage return and a newline combination in as the separator.

Just a newline

```
UPDATE ticket
SET comments  = CONCAT('def', COALESCE(CONCAT(CHAR(10),comments),''))
WHERE ticket = 25;
```

Or to be CRLF:

```
UPDATE ticket
SET comments  = CONCAT('def', COALESCE(CONCAT(CHAR(13),CHAR(10),comments),''))
WHERE ticket = 25;
```

Comment: This is working fine. Thanks for the help. This query indeed makes the value to enter in a new line in the database. But when I am retrieving the data from the database the entire content is displayed as in the form of a paragraph. Is there any way I can write a select query which will retrieve the data in different lines from the database?

Comment: @user3411959 - `Being displayed as a paragraph` - Do you mean via HTML? You could prepend the string with '<p>' and append with with '</p>'. Then replace every CHAR(10) with '</p><p>'

Comment: I am using the query " select comments from ticket where ticket_id=235 " and getting the results to a variable. I am then using document.getelementbyID('test').innerHTML=variable function to take the data in an id. After this I am displaying the data by <p id="test"></p>. Can you please tell me exactly where can I do the prepend and append operations?

Comment: @Durbar - Try changing your SQL to this `SELECT CONCAT('<p>',REPLACE(comments, CHAR(10), '</p><p>'),'</p>') ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
u can try this  
  UPDATE ticket
    SET comments  = CONCAT(COALESCE(comments),CHAR(13), CHAR(10),'def')
    WHERE ticket_id = 235;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would honestly suggest having comments to a ticket in a separate table that you can join to the ticket itself.

That being said, your current approach should work, though I would make the concatenation like this:

```
UPDATE ticket 
SET comments = concat(COALESCE(comments,''), 'def' ) 
WHERE ticket_id = 235;
```

I don't know where the semicolon in your example is coming from unless it is in teh per-existing field value.  The only change here is to `COALESCE` the current filed value with an empty string to handle a case where the current value is `null`.  Using `COALESCE` with a single argument basically makes no sense (unless in a `GROUP BY`/`COALESCE` context in `SELECT` query).